# Implementing "Except" SQL Operation in MS Access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I think that I should explain my problem a little bit in detail. May be you can help me to solve it.

I want to save a resault of a query in a "Temporary" Table hence I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT *
INTO Temp_tbl
FROM (tb_KonzeptDaten LEFT JOIN tb_Fahrzeug ON tb_KonzeptDaten.Konzept = tb_Fahrzeug.ID) LEFT JOIN tb_MSG ON tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG = tb_MSG.ID
```

I got the error 3090 which says "Resultant table not allowed to have more than one AutoNumber field."

that was correct! in eac of these three table I have an autonumber field

then I've deceided to select all fields without these Autonumber fields and then I've found that we can do this job with SQL **EXCEPT** operator but unfortunatlly it seems that this operator doesn't work in  MS Access 2003

then I tried to use SQL "NOT EXIST" operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM (tb_KonzeptDaten LEFT JOIN tb_Fahrzeug ON tb_KonzeptDaten.Konzept = tb_Fahrzeug.ID) LEFT JOIN tb_MSG ON tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG = tb_MSG.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT tb_KonzeptDaten.ID FROM tb_KonzeptDaten)
```

but I didn't get my desired answer

What do you mean? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: except is not for selecting columns, it works on whole result sets. Instead of using `select *` you will have to list each column separately: `select tb_Msg.col1, tb_Msg.col2, ...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to find another way because I have more than 30 fields and I don't want to write the name of all these fields with a complex name. Don't I have another way to do this jo?

Comment: Writing the 30 columns should haven taken less time that writing this question

Comment: If you don't want to write out the names of the fields, use the Query Designer in Access to generate the `SELECT` statement, switch to SQL view, copy the text and add the rest of your code.